# Company mode does not complete automatically

Tags: company-mode

So I have installed company mode with the backend company-gtags. This is what my init file looks like for company.

```
;; == company-mode ==
(use-package company
  :diminish company-mode
  :ensure t
  :init (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
  :config
  (setq company-idle-delay              0.1
        company-minimum-prefix-length   2
        company-show-numbers            t
        company-tooltip-limit           20
        company-dabbrev-downcase        nil
        company-backends                '((company-gtags))
      )
  :bind ("s-;" . company-complete-common)
  )
```

When I type part of a variable/function, and wait for company to autocomplete, nothing happens. Then when I press s-; I see the popup with completions.

However, I would like for company to start the completion automatically and I am not sure what I am missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Please leave a comment, at least, when you figure out what the problem was

Answer (score 1):

The configuration looks all right. There could be something wrong with your gtags setting.

For what it's worth, I think you should use `company-complete` instead.

`company-complete`:

> Insert the common part of all candidates or the current selection.
>   The first time this is called, the common part is inserted, the **second
>   time**, or when the selection has been changed, the selected candidate is
>   inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out that `company-begin-commands` was screwed by some configuration I copied from sombody else. The value defines when company completion should be triggered. The default for the value is:

```
'(self-insert-command
  org-self-insert-command
  orgtbl-self-insert-command
  c-scope-operator
  c-electric-colon
  c-electric-lt-gt
  c-electric-slash)
```

Make sure this variable contains at least `self-insert-command` so that a popup can be triggered by normal typing.

Answer (score 0):

`company` should work out of box if you:

- build tags using GNU Global
- set up environment variable `GTAGSLIBPATH`

See https://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html